# Transit Visa for flight connecting through Narita/Japan airport

Tags: air-travel, ana

Vietnamese passport with US green Card. Flying to Vietnam on February 2023. Do I need a transit visa if my layover is 2 hour at the NARITA/Japan Airport

Answer (score 2):

If you have your flight under a **single** ticket/PNR :

TIMATIC states :

> > Japan - Transit Visa
> > Visa required.
> > **TWOV (Transit Without Visa)**
>
> > Passengers with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country on the same calendar day. They must stay in the international
> > transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next
> > destination.

Else you will need a visa